# Vuetify v-img wrong size on Firefox

Tags: html, vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js, vuetify.js

I have the following snipped in my Nuxt(2.15.8) and Vuetify (2.6.3) project.

```html
<v-row cols="12" class="mt-md-10">
  <v-col md="6" sm="12" align="center">
    <v-img contain class="pa-2" :src="cloudImage"></v-img>
      <div id="wifi" class="d-block mt-15">
        <v-img contain max-width="100" :src="wave1"></v-img>
        <v-img contain max-width="131" :src="wave2"></v-img>
        <v-img contain max-width="171" :src="wave3"></v-img>
      </div>
  </v-col>
</v-row>
```

But I have three different results in the end:

- Safari (15.3)  ✔
- Chrome         ✔
- Edge           ✔
- Firefox (97.0) X

For all the browsers (on the right) the waves are correctly displayed, on Firefox the SVG height and width are automatically put as squared.

If we use `<img />` instead of `<v-img />` the situation seems to be better but we loose the responsiveness of vuetify.

[image: Left Firefox Right all the others]

Any help or hint from you?

Comment: The fastest would be to inspect the element and see if there is something missing or not supported in Firefox vs the others.

Comment: Would be awesome for me to have enough experience in this technology to inspect the code and find the bug.  
For now everything I have done is to use `<img>` instead of `<v-img>` and see in this question if anyone else had a similar problem and how to solve it.

Comment: Open the devtools (in your browser) and check the DOM, still the fastest and easiest way to debug this. Also, you can check the Github issues but it may be a long shot to expect an answer that scoped.